# Run commands before each "docker compose run"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Each time I run `docker compose run my_container <any command>`, I want the following to get evaluated before my command runs:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
ssh-add /root/.ssh/deployment.pem
```

However, I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried adding something for `ENTRYPOINT`, but that makes it so my entrypoint script gets run instead of whatever I try to run using `docker compose run`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to run these commands inside the container? If so, their natural place is in the Dockerfile (which should add the `eval` part to the boot script of the root user). I wouldn't contaminate entrypoints or compose commands. It belongs in the build.

Comment: It seems like you'd need to run this outside the container?  You could write a script to wrap `docker-compose` that did this.

Comment: Yes, I want to run these commands inside the container. But `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` starts a process, and unless I'm mistaken, commands run during the build process won't "last" until runtime.